# Image not showing or not loading after downloading app from play store in react native

Tags: react-native, image, android-app-bundle

Image not showing or not loading after downloading app from play store in react native.

I have code like this =

```
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            width: wp("100%"),
            height: hp("100%"),
            resizeMode: "stretch",
          }}
          source={IMAGES.loginScreenImg}
        />

.... more code ....
```

this image is showing perfectly on debug mode and also after creating apk but when I make aab file and upload it on play store. and then download it then its not showing or not loading. please guide me

Comment: can you please try to create build from command in terminal?
first create release apk using ```./gradlew assembleRelease``` or ```gradlew assembleRelease" then install apk on real device

Comment: yes in this apk the image showing perfectly.

Comment: ok now create build using ```gradlew bundleRelease``` or ```./gradlew bundleRelease``` then try to upload file and check